# Translating ActionScript3's ByteArray uncompress() to Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, actionscript-3, zlib, deflate

I've created the below sample code in ActionScript3 to deflate-uncompress a string:

```
    var byteArray = new ByteArray();
    byteArray.position = 0;
    byteArray.writeUTF("stackoverflow");
    byteArray.compress("deflate");
    trace("Compressed: " + byteArray.toString());
    byteArray.uncompress("deflate");
    trace("Uncompressed: " + byteArray.toString());
```

It seems that ActionScript3 modifies RFC1951 slightly to remove the headers. At this time, I am unable to replicate the code snippet in Python 3. I have tried using the Py3AMF library, however I did not see a method to do deflate uncompress.

Thanks!

Comment: They explain the compression algorithms here: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#compress()

Comment: @Organis as I stated in my original post, the Adobe reference specifies that they use RFC1951 which isn't entirely accurate since the compressed data does not contain the proper headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it! Solution is to use

> -zlib.MAX_WBITS

Here's a code snippet in Python 3:

```
f = open("decode.txt", "rb")
data = f.readline()
print(data)
print((zlib.decompress(data, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)).decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Kudos for solving it and for sharing the solution as well.